# Functional mapping on a list of points

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of points:

```
points = {{0.144, 1.20}, {0.110, 1.60}, {0.083, 2.00}, {0.070, 2.40},
         {0.060, 2.80}, {0.053, 3.20}, {0.050, 3.60}, {0.043, 4.00}}
```

I want to pass each point to this function, returning a new point:

```
coordinate[length_,frequence_] = {(1/(2*length)) , (frequence*1000)}
```

Which should result in a list like so:

```
 { {3.47, 12 000}, {4.54, 16 000}, ... }
```

I've been trying to do so with map:

```
 data = Map[coordinate, points]
```

It yields something like:

```
 {coordinate[{0.144, 1.2}], coordinate[{0.11, 1.6}]}
```

At first that seems correct, except it passes a list rather than just arguments. However, even if I change my `coordinate` function to accept a list (by changing the expected parameter to `list_` and changing `length` to `list[[1]]` and `frequence` to `list[[2]]`), I won't be able to use the list returned by that map for e.g. linear regression by `LinearModelFit[data, x, x]["BestFit"]`.

Comment: for the record, in English the word is `frequency`; `frequence` is technically acceptable I think but never ever used

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way that uses your definition, is *`Apply` at level 1* which has the shorthand `@@@`. (See the more info part of the [Apply documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).) So, you want

```
points = {{0.144, 1.20}, {0.110, 1.60}, {0.083, 2.00}, {0.070, 
   2.40}, {0.060, 2.80}, {0.053, 3.20}, {0.050, 3.60}, {0.043, 4.00}}

coordinate[length_, frequence_] := {(1/(2*length)), (frequence*1000)}

coordinate @@@ points
```

Note that I've changed your definition into a `SetDelayed` instead of just `Set` (pay attention to the syntax highlighting showing you the localized variables on the right hand side). See the [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) guide page.

This said, it's probably best to make `coordinate` take a list instead of a sequence, as done in belisarius' and ninjagecko's answers, i.e.,

```
coordinate[{length_, frequence_}] := {(1/(2*length)), (frequence*1000)}
```

Comment: Personally I like the `Apply[.., 1]` approach better -- I think it makes for code that is easier to read/write.  (For some reason I have an aversion to using `Part` unless I absolutely have to...)

Comment: @Brett I share your feeling regarding the aesthetics, but sometimes I'd choose the `Part` - based one due to the performance considerations. For large lists, using `Apply` will generally prevent auto-compilation. Does not matter if we define `coordinate` with patterns, but does matter if we use pure functions like `coordinate = {#/2, #2*1000} &` for `Apply[...,1]` and `coordinatePart =  {#[[1]]/2, #[[2]]*1000} &` for `Map`. Using a test sample like `pointsFreqs = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {100000, 2}];`, you can observe significant performance advantage of auto-compiling `Map` over `Apply`.

Comment: @Brett: I agree, using `Part` looks ugly and make the code harder to read: "*what doe the variable `list[[2]]` refer to?*".  (Edit: although Leonid does make a good point!)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer on Apply/Map and the Set/SetDelayed reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
coordinate[{length_, frequence_}] := {(1/(2*length)), (frequence*1000)}
data = coordinate /@ points
(*
->{{3.47222, 1200.}, {4.54545, 1600.}, {...
*)
```

And

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
(*
-> -40.3573 + 348.678 x
*)

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 15}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make the graph go from 0 to 15? I have what seems to be the exact same code as you, however, my graph starts immediately after the first point: https://gist.github.com/e0fedb1281339298706f

Comment: @Sirupsen `Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 15}]`

Comment: I've rerun it in new documents to make sure it wasn't some cache mistake, and it's the same result. Guess it's a version conflict. (8.0.1 here). http://cl.ly/Ad9l

Comment: @Sirupsen Try `Show[Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 15}], ListPlot[data],  Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 3):

Change your definition to

```
coordinate[point_] := {(1/(2*point[[1]])) , (point[[2]]*1000)}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
coordinate[{length_, frequence_}] := {1/(2*length), frequence*1000}
coordinate /@ points
```

sidenote: I would personally stay away from the `@@@` that has been proposed in other answers, since it feels awkward to me as a programmer. But those answers are also certainly valid.

Comment: oops, I made a typo and didn't do `:=`. Anything this is what you want because anything inside `[`...`]` can be a pattern, e.g. `coordinate[PATTERN]`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `Apply` instead of `Map`:

```
coordinate @@@ points
```

output:

```
{{3.47222, 1200.}, {4.54545, 1600.}, {6.0241, 2000.}, {7.14286, 2400.}, 
 {8.33333, 2800.}, {9.43396, 3200.}, {10., 3600.}, {11.6279, 4000.}}
```

Comment: Not disagreeing with the answer. For the record though, while `@@@` is technically calling `Apply`, Mathematica defines `Apply` in a weird way. I'd say `@@@` is more like currying `Apply[#1, ???]` (with the first argument), then `Map`ping the resulting anonymous function over the second argument. (At least according to most other definitions of `Apply`.)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that `@@@` is the cleanest way to handle this.  However, if you can to redefine `coordinate` but you do not want remove its existing syntax, you may consider this construct.

```
Clear[coordinate]
coordinate[length_, frequence_] := {(2 length)^-1, 1000 frequence}
coordinate[l_List] := Apply[coordinate, l, {-2}]
```

The new line adds a definition to handle lists.  This assumes that your arguments are not themselves objects with depth.  It allows for quite a bit of flexibility in the way you use the function:

```
coordinate[0.144, 1.20]

(*Out= {3.47222, 1200.} *)

coordinate[{0.144, 1.20}]

(*Out= {3.47222, 1200.} *)

coordinate[points]

(*Out= {{3.47222, 1200.}, {4.54545, 1600.}, {6.0241, 
  2000.}, {7.14286, 2400.}, {8.33333, 2800.}, {9.43396, 3200.}, {10., 
  3600.}, {11.6279, 4000.}} *)

coordinate /@ points

(*Out= {{3.47222, 1200.}, {4.54545, 1600.}, {6.0241, 
  2000.}, {7.14286, 2400.}, {8.33333, 2800.}, {9.43396, 3200.}, {10., 
  3600.}, {11.6279, 4000.}} *)

coordinate @@@ points

(*Out= {{3.47222, 1200.}, {4.54545, 1600.}, {6.0241, 
  2000.}, {7.14286, 2400.}, {8.33333, 2800.}, {9.43396, 3200.}, {10., 
  3600.}, {11.6279, 4000.}} *)
```

Comment: Have you seen the [Mathematica proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica?referrer=N-NhurYzOmcl8-Pye4BdZw2) at Area51? It used to be in the "Definition" phase for a while but we managed to push it into "Commitment" and it's steadily growing. I didn't see your name in the list, so just letting you know so that you can join!

Comment: @yoda Okay, I took a look at it, but I don't really see the point.  It seems to me that StackOverflow, CodeReview, etc., are already available.  I don't believe there is an all-encompassing C# SE site; why do you feel we need a Mathematica one?

Comment: Mma is more of a complete package rather than just a language and that leads to fragmentation between existing sites. Half the questions asked on [so] shouldn't be asked here. We just are accepting of it and don't close.  If you want examples of sites that have successfully branched off from SO, you can look at [wordpress.se], [drupal.se] and [sharepoint.se].

Comment: @yoda But also look at Code Golf. Golfing questions received a lot of attention here, and (I think) it was fun. The new site instead has very low traffic, and most answers never get upvoted. Example:http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/solve-the-knapsack-problem

Comment: @belisarius Fair enough, you have a point there... I guess we'll cross the bridge when we get to it. I wouldn't be surprised if they shut it down in beta because the questions are a perfect fit for [so] :D

Comment: @yoda I recently found a lonely post on CodeReview waiting for attention.  I can see this as either an argument for, or against your proposal.  On the one hand, such a question would have been placed with other Mathematica questions and likely had more exposure.  On the other, all Mathematica questions might get less exposure.  Belisarius and you are two users who do not specialize in [mathematica] on SO; how do you feel about having to visit another site?  How would that compare for (in)convenience to simply setting up a filter on stackexchange.com for all Mathematica questions on all sites?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You can see from my profile that I spend a considerable amount of time on several other sites doing other stuff too. It does take my time away from [so], but on the other hand, I find my SO experience more enjoyable and less of a manic rep-hunt. Given that nearly half my time on SO (3/4 these days) is spent in the mma tag, the only thing that would happen is that I'd probably divert my attention from SO to the other site.

Comment: My main motivation for supporting it is that I don't see mma users as programmers first. Everyone is probably a scientist/hobbyist/researcher first who happens to do programming in mma. As such, a lot of the questions are not about "Why should I place a comma here", "Why should I indent this", etc., but require a little more involved math/domain specific knowledge (I've seen that people are willing to learn new areas to help just because it's interesting and the challenge of doing with mma). So I really see the site as an intersection of [math.se], [so], [codereview.se] and maybe [physics.se]

Comment: @yoda I think I better understand your perspective now.  (I was about to add my support, but I think I need to read about the process first.)